# AWS S3 403 Forbitten error when trying to upload a image with React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement an image upload system on my React app and upload that image to
AWS S. With the code I have when I upload the image I get an error 403 forbidden.
I have tried multiple methods nothing works, I have checked the settings a hundred times still the same error message. Of course when the credentials are not okay I get 400 error bad request. Is this client side problem or server side?

I am also using CORS add-on to bypass, it works with other APIs no problem.
Here is the simple code I am using

```
import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3';
import React from 'react'
import S3 from 'react-aws-s3'

const FileUpload = () => {
    const fileuploader= (e) => {
    
        const config = {
            bucketName: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
            accessKeyId:process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_ID,
            secretAccessKey:process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY
        }
       const file = e.target.files[0]
       console.log(file)                 
        
        const ReactS3Client = new S3(config)
        ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file,config)
        .then( data => {console.log(data)})
        .catch(err => alert(err))    
    }


    return(
        <>
        <input
        type="file"
        onChange={fileuploader}
        />
        </>
    )

}

export default FileUpload
```

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Does the upload work if you try doing this manually using same credentails/role as your reactjs?

Comment: Nope it does not work, I get the same error, the link I get is working correctly. I have read many posts saying error 400 or error 403 appears because of the region, which I am sure this is not the case since other APIs work